# Get post publish date inside ACF foreach

Tags: wordpress

In the post loop I have a foreach loop which displays selected team members in the admin(from the "team" custom post type) from an ACF post object.

What I want to achieve is to display the post-publish date inside the foreach.

The problem is that the code `echo get_the_date('M d, Y');` shows the date of the "team" custom post type and not the blog post date because is in the foreach.

I tried to pass the post id but it's shows the posts id of the "team" post types and not the actual "post".

How can I show the `'post_type' => 'post'`  publish post date inside in the foreach?

```
<?php
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DSC'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

    $postAuthors = get_field('select_post_author'); // ACF post object - custom post type - team
    
    if( $postAuthors ): ?>
        <?php foreach( array_slice($postAuthors, 0, 1) as $post): ?>
            <div class="post-date">
                <span>
                    <?php
                        echo get_the_date('M d, Y');  // here I want to get the post publish date but it show the publish date of the team post type items
                    ?>
                </span>
            </div><!-- /.post-date -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?> 

<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of `array_slice($postAuthors, 0, 1)` statement in the `foreach`?

Comment: This code limits the results to 1 on the post listing page.

This approach will show only 1 author on the post listing page, and on the single page it will show all authors associated with the post.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is due to `$post` being a global variable. I assume ACF stores an array of posts for `get_field('select_post_author')` then you need to change your `foreach` statement local variable name, e.g:

```
 <?php foreach( array_slice($postAuthors, 0, 1) as $postAuthor): ?>
     <div class="post-date">
         <span>
             <?php echo get_the_date('M d, Y', $postAuthor->ID); ?>
         </span>
     </div><!-- /.post-date -->
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thak you for the help, Plamen.

 I solved the issue by passing the post id in the get_the_date.

I swear that I tried this and it didn't work. 

Maybe I was too tired and made a mistake.

Comment: The issue was in the variable name, you cannot use `$post` in the foreach body as it will have side effects because this is a global var define outside of the loop. Can you mark my answer here as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by passing the post id in the date.

```
<?php
$pid = get_the_ID(); //get the post id
$postAuthors = get_field('select_post_author');
 if( $postAuthors ): ?>
```

Pass the post id in the get_the_date.

```
echo get_the_date('M d, Y',$pid);
```